# May I ask this question?

Tags: support, specific-question

I wonder how I should evaluate different features for my website. The features are mockups at best, and some features are only ideas. I also have good basic functionality deployed, but now I want to evaluate which non-implemented feature that I should work on. Is that a good fit for your site, or is the question too subjective?

Answer (score 4):

This question is really up to your team and your customer. Not really a good fit for UX.SE, since we can't guess what your customer wants. So head over to your project lead and ask what you should do with the features...

Answer (score 1):

I understand you need to test some ideas because it is a problem for each functionality that prevents it from becoming a feature.

I think if you can describe your problem or what you want to know, here, even you add a specific example with a mockup, the users will help you.

It will be ok if the example is the base of a question that can be generalised and can help other people in the future, but if you want just help for testing your website, that will be not useful for other users.